# Is the F-score invariant to confusion matrix transposition?

Tags: confusion-matrix

Is the F-score invariant to confusion matrix transposition?

In other words, if *actual values* are substituted with *predicted values* and vice-versa, would the F-score stay the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the case exactly for $\beta=1$, i.e., for the $F1$ score, but not for general $F\beta$ scores.

To see this, use [the following formulation of the $F\beta$ score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-score):

$$ F\beta = \frac{(1+\beta^2)\cdot TP}{(1+\beta^2)\cdot TP + \beta^2\cdot FN+ FP}. $$

Transposing your [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) will leave $TP$ (and $TN$) unchanged, and exchange $FP$ and $FN$. Thus, $F\beta$ will remain unchanged for all possible $FN$ and $FP$ values exactly for $\beta=1$.

[(Note that the $F\beta$ score is not a good evaluation measure for the exact same reasons that accuracy, precision and recall alone aren't.)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352)